# Сравнение значения в БД ( регистрация пользователя)

Tags: php, база-данных, регистрация

Мой код работает только для одного значения, для первого, после того как пытаюсь добавить второго пользователя он уже не определяет дубликаты видит один элемент масссива, понимаю что нужно как то через цикл, но не пойму как.;

```
$app->get('/addtodb', function () use($app) {

    $name = $app -> request()-> get('name');

    // connecting to db
    $db = new dbconnect();

    $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE name='$name'";
    $res = mysql_query($query); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    echo $row['name'];
    if (!empty($row['id'])) {
        echo 'error';
    }
    else { $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('$name')"); };

});


$app->run();
```

Comment: name = asdf'; Hello from sql-ing --

Comment: непонятно что Вы имели ввиду

Comment: Какова структура таблицы? И да, явно косяк в проверяющем коде

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `phone` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `secondname` text NOT NULL,
  `pass` text NOT NULL,
  `user_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `id_2` (`id`)
)

Comment: Он имел ввиду, что у вас потенциальная sql-инъекция. _Никогда_ не подставляйте значения переменных в текст запроса. Используйте привязываемые переменные см. bind_param.

Comment: Раз уж вы используете фреймворк, то почему ходите через `mysql_query`? Неужели фреймворк не предоставляет инструментов для работы с БД?
У вас в запросе есть два лишних ключа, `id`, `id_2`, их можно убрать, но добавить primary_key.
Вы смотрите в базу напрямую, там записи вообще появляются?

Answer (score 1):

Цикл здесь не нужен. Судя по Вашему исходнику, во-первых и главных ни как не проверяется значение, которое подставляется в запрос. О том, как делать правильно в сети множество текстов. Изучите объектный подход к msqli, prepare и т. п.

Кроме того, вы так и не предоставили актуальную версию исходника структуры таблицы, либо очень перемудрили при её создании - пара одинаковых ключей по id явно - перебор.

В целом, проще взять, да переписать всё с нуля, чем править. Правильный подход - гарантировать уникальность нужных полей на уровне бд. В этом случае можно просто закидывать значения, если они конфликтуют с уникальными ключами - база не изменится, можно будет посмотреть код ошибки.

Похоже, что вы занимаетесь самообразованием. Это прекрасно. В этом случае крайне необходимо понять, что за запрос формируется. Рекомендую в текущей версии проверить, что попадает в переменную `$query`. Вполне возможно, что Вы увидите ошибку.